# Google People API request

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, google-api, google-people-api

Hi currently using people API by google, But i am having some errors on request "api.client.people.people.connections.list" on API.

The picture below will show the error, The first picture is the console error. and the other one is the code error it shows that the list is cannot read property of undefined. The code is in below.

[image]

```
    var request = gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
    'resourceName': 'people/me',
    'requestMask.includeField': ['person.phoneNumbers', 'person.names','person.emailAddresses'],
    'sortOrder' : 'FIRST_NAME_ASCENDING',
    'pageSize': 500,
});
```

Comment: please supply us with a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is my code in requesting gapi.client.people.people.connections

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the **error message and stack trace** as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find solution? I figured out that there is no ```gapi.client.people.people.connections.list ```  but ```gapi.client.people.people.me.connections.list and``` and list is always comes empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this too, their tutorial here has the same problem https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/js.

Now you have to do `gapi.client.people.people.me.connections.list`

And `list` doesn't take a `resourceName` param anymore, you can see that here https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list.

It would be nice if they would update their tutorial...

Answer (score 1):

This works today.

```
    gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
```

The accepted answer was posted in 2017 so the API has probably changed somehow, but I copied the code for the above function and the call works for me. You can find the full source at: https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/js

Comment: Weird. Google actually fixed a bug.